# UL Won't Center In Mobile View

Tags: css, html-lists, center

I am mobilizing a website using media queries that take effect at 650px and below. For whatever reason, I can not get my navigation menu to center in the page. My navigation menu is in an unorderd list. I spent over an hour in FireBug trying to figure this thing out without any success. Can some css Guru out there please help me with this!!?

Here is the site...
http://shoponlinedemo.com/junkyard-zombiez/

Comment: Could you please paste some html and css so we can see where you might be going wrong, if you could also add the code to jsfiddle.net that would also be great.

Comment: I added a zip file with ll of the resources at... http://shoponlinedemo.com/junkyard-zombiez/Junkyard-Zombiez.zip In the junkyardzombie.css file, near the bottom of the file, you will see my new rules for the media query.

Comment: The <ul> that I am trying to center is on line 81 of the index.htm file.

Comment: I have a fix for you below :)

Comment: Thanx again Jay. Goodnight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your @media all and (max-width:650px) section of your css you should make the following changes:

```
#navigation, .menu {
   width:100%;
}

.menu .menu-item {
   float:none;
   margin-left:auto;
   margin-right:auto;
   display:block
}
```

in order for margin:auto to center your content it will need to have a container which takes up the entire width or is centered itself. Also for margin:auto to work the element being centered needs to have a set width.

Since your lis may need to change width and ideally would stay centered regardless of their width, it would be best to have all of the lis in a container that is 100% the width of the browser for mobile, and then center them within that container. this is why you will need to make the navigation and menu divs 100% width.

In addition you cannot center a floated div, so you will need to clear that float from the lis. then simply apply display:block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto; and you will have a centered menu!

Comment: You are the css god! This is even better than the first fix. I would like to give a big thank you to both of you guys! I updated the files on the server. There you can see how it renders perfectly. And thank you for that explanation. Divs and floats have always been somewhat confusing.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have alot of conflicting styles here, like float:left on containing divs etc, ive been playing in firebug, i think the quickest and easiest fix for this problem would be this css.(Ensure you only use this css at the page width you require;

```
@media all and (max-width: 650px) {
    #navigation {
        clear: left;
        float: left;
        height: auto;
        margin-left: 25%;
        margin-right: 25%;
        margin-top: 0;
        width: 50%;
    }
    #navigation li {
     width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: I applied your fix and it centers now. Thank you very much sir! One thing is... onMouseover / hover it resizes the background image.

Comment: I updated the files on the server so if you refresh your browser you will see this behavior.

Comment: Your most welcome Alex please mark the post as answered for future viewers, This is the css which is causing the problem; .menu a:hover {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

Comment: Change the css to background: inherit;

Comment: In my stylesheet there is only one rule that begins like the one you mention above and it is on line 70 and does not have same attributes as you mention.

Comment: I am see that style in firebug http://shoponlinedemo.com/junkyard-zombiez/Junkyard%20Zombiez%20%20%20Story_files/junkyardzombie.css line 70.

try this css (inside the 650px media query; #navigation a:hover { background: inherit !important;}

This should fix it for you.